# Spectrum ERROR: Failed to incorporate external table

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Redshift Spectrum is giving the below error which executing the SELECT statements for the external table created.

```
ERROR:  Failed to incorporate external table "schmaname"."tablename" into local catalog.
```

The external table has limited number of columns, say 50.

I can query on the same table with the superuser and with a different set of a user without any issues. Is there any user settings need to be changed apart from the GRANT

Comment: Did you try granting `USAGE` on the schema to the user?

Comment: yes, `USAGE` and `SELECT` grants are applied to the user on the particular schema.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the OP got his answer but for others, here are the probable causes collated from various sources:

> 1) No. of columns in external table exceeded the limit of 1598
>
> 2) Column names of external table using reserved keywords

Another post with same issue and solutions:

[AWS Redshift - Failed to incorporate external table into local catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051804/aws-redshift-failed-to-incorporate-external-table-into-local-catalog)